# ionic cli 3.2.0 error-TypeError: AppScripts.processProviderRequest is not a function

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to create login /signup using [this](https://devdactic.com/login-ionic-2/) tutorial.
When I run ionic g provider authService I receive the error `TypeError`: `AppScripts.processProviderRequest` is not a function.

I have updated the node.js and my ionic-angular to the latest version but has not helped.

```
global packages: 
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.2.0 
Ionic CLI : 3.2.0 

local packages: 
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.1.4 
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.2.0 
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.3.0 

System: 
Node : v6.10.3 
OS : Windows 10 
Xcode : not installed 
ios-deploy : not installed 
ios-sim : not installed
```

Please Help!

Comment: global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.2.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.2.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.1.4
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.2.0
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0

System:

    Node       : v6.10.3
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed

Comment: can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44223347/edit) your post and also include your package.json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this worked for me by running the below script in the cmd

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```

Example: `C:\Source\Examples\Ionic\NewWebApp\NewWebApp>npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest`

Answer (score 2):

> @ionic/app-scripts : 1.1.4

It looks like your app scripts is of an old version.

Refer to the [package.json](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json) in the starter app code to update it. This is the package from which the app is downloaded when you do  `ionic start` command.

```
"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7"
```

You can also verify any other dependency issues you may have from the starter app.

Comment: Thanks Alot. I have updated my app scripts using  npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest and its now working. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: glad it worked :) consider accepting the answer to close the issue